# Is it possible to determine the execution order of GHUnit test methods?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, cocoa, unit-testing, gh-unit

This must sound like a severe case of the GIYF-itis, but I can't find anything useful out there.

It looks like test methods in [GHUnit](https://github.com/gabriel/gh-unit) are executed in alphabetical order. I am all for it that every test case/class should be testable on its own, but I do want to be able to test a certain sequence *without ruining semantics by naming them testA, testB etc*.

Is there a way to do this with GHUnit? Cheers.

Comment: Wow 17 hours, 11 views. GHUnit sure isn't popular these days is it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently, there is not. If you want to sort your test method calls, just use a different naming scheme for your test methods, like `test_01_zOperation` and `test_02_aOperation`.